# Trying to understand a probability question/concept

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

[Discrete Probability: Four dice are thrown, what's the probability that...](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3115334/discrete-probability-four-dice-are-thrown-whats-the-probability-that/3115348?noredirect=1#comment6419101_3115348)

So I made a post and there were a lot of incorrect answers, and two people were able to provide the correct answers, but I cannot understand *why* or *how* they got it.

So for this particular question: A dice is thrown four times, what's the probability "four" is the highest number thrown?

Okay, so what I understand is the sample space is $6^4$. Now we need to find the probability that $4$ is the highest number thrown. So that eliminates 2 other possible outcomes, 5 and 6. So we have 4 possible outcomes now. So $\frac{4^{4}}{6^{4}}$. But now what I cannot understand is *why* on earth do we need to subtract the number of possibilities where none of the numbers fall higher than 3? Like why does it matter? What if 4 is rolled all the time? Who cares?

Comment: When you consider the event that the maximum is less than or equal to $4$, it includes the case where it is less than $4$, which you do not want - you want the maximum equals to $4$. So you subtract the unwanted case, getting the relative complement of the event.

Comment: “4 is the highest “ also means that a 4 had to happen.

Answer (score 1):

There are $4^4$ ways in which we can roll either $1$, $2$, $3$ or $4$ in $4$ rolls of a die. But this includes the situations in which no $4$ is rolled. In these cases $4$ is not the maximum number. The number of ways in which we can roll the numbers $1$, $2$ or $3$ exclusively is $3^4$. So the probability of rolling $4$ as the highest number is $4^4-3^4$ divided by the sample space - $6^4$.
$$\frac{4^4-3^4}{6^4}=\frac{175}{1296}$$

Answer (score 0):

The $4^4$ is the number of ways to get all $4$ dice rolls be between $1$ and $4$ (inclusive). However, this also includes the $3^4$ cases where all the dice rolls were between $1$ and $3$. We do not want to include these cases (since if all dice rolls are between $1$ and $3$, then the maximum roll cannot be $4$, because $4$ isn't rolled!). Therefore, we subtract it off.